# Concrete 5.8 Express Entry Block - Filter results by attribute

Tags: php, oop, orm, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

Following the Developer documentation [here](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/express/using-the-express-entry-block-to-output-entry-data) is it possible to go further and filter the results by the object's attributes?

For example, say you had multiple boats in a Marina that had the same owner and you wanted to find only that owner's boats in the Marina is there a way of filtering the data down further (ie filter by the attribute BoatOwner).

After much reading of the Doctrine2 documentation I can understand that this can be done but I can't work out how to extend the C5 code or what methods I can call to do this.

```
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied.")); ?>
<?php

if (isset($entry) && is_object($entry)) {

$boats = $entry->getBoats();

?>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>Classification</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php if (count($boats)) {
    foreach($boats as $boat) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$boat->getBoatName()?></td>
            <td><?=$boat->getBoatYear()?></td>
            <td><?=$boat->getBoatOwner()?></td>
            <td><?=$boat->getBoatClass()?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">No boats found.</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

The above is the code from the C5 documentation. Can the magic "get" method be extended in some way or is there a simpler solution working with the $boats array (I think it's an array) to select only the boats with a certain attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to place an if statement with the foreach loop.

```
if (count($boats)) {
    foreach($boats as $boat) { 
if($boat->getBoatOwner() == "boat owner's name here") {
?>
<tr>
        <td><?=$boat->getBoatName()?></td>
        <td><?=$boat->getBoatYear()?></td>
        <td><?=$boat->getBoatOwner()?></td>
        <td><?=$boat->getBoatClass()?></td>
    </tr>

<?php;
            } else {
                ?>

    <?php;
            } 



        ?>



        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No boats found.</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm thinking I will pass the boat owner's name as a variable probably from page attribute for this to be of any use.